# iOS core data:how to use preloaded sqlite database which contains multiple tables

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, ios5, sqlite

my app has a sqlite database which is already preloaded with data. the database has many tables. i want to show a list of tables, so i have to query database or just list my entities?! when user taps a table name the next uitableview shows the data of that specified table. there are no relations between tables. only selecting from database matters right now.
what would be the best way to go forward? sqlite api or core data. i'm new to iOS programming. i'm reading about core data. it sounds good but i'm perplexed how to solve this problem.

edit:by the way the table are identical. all of them have the same attributes. i have spilted in tables so that each table represent a category, and i suppose it would best for memory usage on the iDevices.

Comment: Regarding your last point - this is probably a waste of effort. If you use core data and fetch requests, you would be best off having a single table/entity and the category as an attribute.

Comment: having all data in one table wouldnt cause latency? i will probably have over 10K rows of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you try to learn the Core Data methods to deal with your data as object graphs. Its is really worth the effort because you get so much additional functionality for table views, etc. all with great automatic memory management. Memory will easily become quite an issue if you deal with raw SQLite and have a lot of data or complex tables.

Do this:

Create the entities in your core data model. Access the existing SQLite store and recreate all the data for your new core data tables. This is normally quite memory and processor intensive, so you typically do this on the simulator, not on the device.

After you have successfully imported the data, you can remove the sqlite libraries and import functions and work with your true core data persistent store.

This is a bit of effort, but I guarantee it is well worth it.

Comment: so you mean i should migrate my sqlite to true core data. i will prefer that also, but i want to keep the option open for future update of the tables. it might get additional attributes and bulk insert of data into columns. so is there a way that one can do bulk insert the data with core data?

Comment: Right. If there are changes in the future, just keep your importing code and adjust it later as necessary. I did this several times and it is a viable process.

Comment: and how do i do the data migration? i mean when i import all sqlite data into core data, it happens on the device/simulator so there is no copy of it in my xcode project, right? where is the core database saved? when i deploy the app it shouldnt do the data import, cause it may take longer to process. any suggestion on that?

Comment: Yes, you import it into a new core data store (which is also a sqlite database). You then locate this database in the application documents  directory of the simulator (something like `~Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulators/5.0/Applications/<longIDCode>/Documents` and copy it to your application bundle. On first run, copy this seed data to the app documents directory again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use SQLite since you already have populated .sqlite file. If you want to painlessly use SQLite I suggest getting along with [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

As for the way that your tables are identical I can only advice you to create a shared method like `- (void)itemsWithCategory:(NSString *)category` and your whole DB communications will be through this function.

Comment: thanks for the idea. i want a shared communication whether core date or sqlite api. i have already seen FMDB. wouldnt it be best to have less dependencies on external sources? anway i'm coding right now. if someone have other idea. please do let us know.